# phpの文法エラーが分からず・・・

Tags: php, mysql

以下のようにエラーが出てます。 
文法エラーのようですが、書き方間違ってますか？

エラー： 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/php_kadai/php_kadai09/postdone.php on line 48

該当箇所：

```
<?php echo "<img src="$_SESSION["img_data"]"><br><br><br>"; ?>




<?php
require_once('functions.php');
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION["img_data"]);

// $name = $_POST['name'];
// $image_name = $_POST['image_name'];
// $img_data = "images/" . $_FILES["img_data"]["name"];

// $dbh = connectDb();
// $sql = "insert into posts (create_at, name, image_name, img_data) values
//         (now(), :name, :image_name, :img_data)";
// $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
// $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
// $stmt->bindParam(":image_name", $image_name);
// $stmt->bindParam(":img_data", $img_data);


// $stmt->execute();



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>投稿完了ページ</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>画像投稿掲示板</h1>
  <hr>
<div id="wrapper">
<p class="title">下記の内容で投稿致します</p>

<p>投稿者：<?php echo h($_SESSION["name"]); ?></p>

<p class="imagestitle">画像タイトル：<?php echo h($_SESSION["image_name"]); ?></p>

<p>画像ファイル：<br>
  <?php echo $_FILES["img_data"]["name"] . "<br>"; ?>
  <?php echo "<img src="$_SESSION["img_data"]"><br><br><br>"; ?>
</p>

  <p class="return"><a href="posting.php">画像投稿ページへ戻る>></a></p>
  <p class="link"><a href="index.php">画像一覧ヘージはこちら>></a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<?php echo "<img src="$_SESSION["img_data"]"><br><br><br>"; ?>` の部分

文字列つまり`"`と`"`で挟まれた部分に`"`を書くには`\`でエスケープする必要があります。
それで、次のように書きます。
`echo "<img src=\"$_SESSION[img_data]\"><br><br><br>";`

`"img_data"`の部分は文字列に埋め込まれている場合`"`は書きません。

Comment: なるほど、ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

```
"<img src="$_SESSION["img_data"]"><br><br><br>"
```

２つの`"`で囲まれた文字列（`"<img src="`と`"><br><br><br>"`）と、1つの変数（`$_SESSION["img_data"]`）ですから、`.`で結合するなどしなくてはなりません：

```
"<img src=" . $_SESSION["img_data"] . "><br><br><br>"
```